# Does R have a base function that takes a predicate and a vector as arguments, and returns the first member for which the predicate is true?

Tags: r, match

I thought that `match` or `which` would be up to the task, but they appear to not be. For example, assume that I have the function `divisibleByFive<-function(x){x%%5==0}` and I want to find the first member of the vector (either its index or its value) `123:456` such that `divisibleByFive` returns `true`. Is there a single base function for this job, taking both `divisibleByFive` (possibly vectorized) and `123:456` as arguments? If not, what is the idiomatic way to solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: Is this what you mean?: `x <- 123:456; x[min(which(x %% 5 == 0))] = 125`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` and `Position`.

```
divisibleByFive<-function(x){x%%5==0}
Find(divisibleByFive,123:456)#For the desired value.
Position(divisibleByFive,123:456)#For the index of the desired value
```

Output:

```
> Find(divisibleByFive,123:456)#For the desired value.
[1] 125

> Position(divisibleByFive,123:456)#For the index of the desired value
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that function is `Filter`. Try this

```
Filter(divisibleByFive, 123:456)[[1L]]
```

However, I don't really recommend doing so as this function is too generic and thus a bit slow in practice. Usually, what you want can be easily achieved by something like this

```
(x <- 123:456)[[which(divisibleByFive(x))[[1L]]]]
```

, as pointed out by **@SteveM**. See the benchmark

```
Unit: microseconds
                                              expr   min     lq    mean median    uq   max neval cld
            Filter(divisibleByFive, 123:456)[[1L]] 238.3 245.35 270.543 250.45 275.9 475.4   100   b
 (x <- 123:456)[[which(divisibleByFive(x))[[1L]]]]   8.3   9.00  10.099   9.50   9.9  28.5   100  a
```

Comment: `Filter` looks like the best that I'm going to get, but with the existence of functions like `match`, I'm surprised that there's no function like `Filter` that always returns the first result.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `which.max`

```
x[which.max(divisibleByFive(x))]
#[1] 125
```